# Why can't i use function parameters in a record update notation?

Tags: haskell

Example of broken code:

```
data Foo = Foo {
    bar :: (Int -> Int)
  }

baz = Foo { bar i = i*3 }
```

Why isn't this possible?

Answer (score 15):

It's just a syntactic limitation - I suspect that if this feature has been considered, it would have been rejected because there are straightforward alternatives. Also, if it was  supported, the next question would be why not pattern-matching with multiple clauses, and overall it would just make the language bigger for not all that much gain.

You can use `baz = Foo { bar = \x -> x*3 }` instead for the specific case you've given, or define an auxiliary function.

Comment: If it was a simple design decision, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Sorry if my answer is slightly misleading, it's my educated guesswork rather than certain historical knowledge.

Comment: Ganesh is right, it has been considered and rejected in the name of simplicity.  The design of Haskell doesn't really have any record, except some old mailing lists.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
baz = Foo { bar = (\x -> x*3) }
```